# jQuery validation code

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, validation

Would like some assistance in improving my jQuery validation code. I have some repeated code, but I am not sure how to write it in a way so that I don't have to keep repeating the same code over and over again for different variable names etc... (such as the `if` statement part) My goal is to make it so that I can easily apply it to any other form I create.

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gZhc/1/)

```
(function($) {

    $('.commentForm').submit(function () {

        var error = 'error';

        var name = $(this).find('.name')
        nameVal = name.attr('value')
        email = $(this).find('.email')
        comment = $(this).find('textarea')
        commentVal = comment.html();

        if (!(name.val() === nameVal || name.val() === '' || name.val().length < 3) && 
            !(comment.val() === commentVal || comment.val() === '' || comment.val().length < 3) && 
            validateEmail(email.val())
           ) {
            console.log('Form is good');
            return true;
        } else {

            (name.val() === nameVal || name.val() === '' || name.val().length < 3) ? name.addClass(error) : name.removeClass(error);
            (comment.val() === commentVal || comment.val() === '' || comment.val().length < 3) ? comment.addClass(error) : comment.removeClass(error);
            (!validateEmail(email.val())) ? email.addClass(error) : email.removeClass(error);

            console.log('Form is BAD');
            return false;

        }

    });

    function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }

}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: If you can use plugin, jquery validation plugin comes with email validation. If not, you can have a look at their implementation. You can find it here: http://validation.bassistance.de/email-method/

Comment: Likely moot at this point, but you can remove the check for `$this.val() === ''` as it is true if `$this.val().length < 3` is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This confuses me:

```
name.val() === nameVal
```

The variable `nameVal` is equal to the `value` attribute of `name`. And, the calling `val()` on `name` returns the `value` attribute of `name` so of course they are going to be equal.

I may be missing something here, but I think this is unnecessary.

---

Long chunks of mush like this:

```
(name.val() === nameVal || name.val() === '' || name.val().length < 3) ? name.addClass(error) : name.removeClass(error);
            (comment.val() === commentVal || comment.val() === '' || comment.val().length < 3) ? comment.addClass(error) : comment.removeClass(error);
            (!validateEmail(email.val())) ? email.addClass(error) : email.removeClass(error);
```

and this:

```
!(name.val() === nameVal || name.val() === '' || name.val().length < 3) && 
            !(comment.val() === commentVal || comment.val() === '' || comment.val().length < 3) && 
            validateEmail(email.val())
```

are in no way whatsoever readable. You need to either

- Break this up. Maybe everything here is not necessary.
- Split this into variables and check with the variables.

I think you should go with the first option, because these can be simplified:

---

1:

As I stated above, having

```
name.val() === nameVal
```

is unnecessary. You can just remove this.

---

2:

The value `""` is called a falsey value. That means that `""` can be treated as though it were false.

So, for example, this here:

```
name.val() === ''
```

can be reduced to:

```
!name.val()
```

---

Constantly calling the `.val` function on these elements in each of your conditionals is inefficient. You should store the result of `.val()` in a variable, and just use that for the conditionals (I think `nameVal` should already hold the `.val()` for `name`).

---

Now, for example, one of your conditional chunks becomes:

```
( !nameVal || nameVal.length < 3) ? name.addClass(error) : name.removeClass(error);

(! commentVal || commentVal.length < 3) ? comment.addClass(error) : comment.removeClass(error);

(!validateEmail(email.val())) ? email.addClass(error) : email.removeClass(error);
```

*Where `commentVal` is `comment.val()` and `nameVal` is `name.val()`*

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your if block with:

```
(name.val() === nameVal || name.val() === '' || name.val().length < 3) ? name.addClass(error) : name.removeClass(error);
(comment.val() === commentVal || comment.val() === '' || comment.val().length < 3) ? comment.addClass(error) : comment.removeClass(error);
(!validateEmail(email.val())) ? email.addClass(error) : email.removeClass(error);

if(name.hasClass(error) || comment.hasClass(error) || email.hasClass(error))
{
    console.log('Form is BAD');
    return false;
}
else
{
    console.log('Form is good');
    return true;
}
```

This would run your validation logic once and then look for error classes on the objects